# C# WPF DataGrid only the first item is displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to programming and have been at it around 3-4 months so please take into account i might not understand/know alot of concepts so please try to explain to me in an easy to understand way if possible! I'm having some problem with the DataGrid in WPF. For some reason i can only add one new item to it and after that when i try to add another new item it doesnt show up in the DataGrid. I have set the ItemSoruce of the DataGrid to a List called gridClassValues. And even when i populate the list with new objects the DataGrid doesnt show these new items except for the first one. Here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<WeightGridClass> gridClassValues = new List<WeightGridClass>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void AddWeightToGridButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        gridClassValues.Add(new WeightGridClass { Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid)});
        WeightDataGrid.ItemsSource = gridClassValues;

    }

    class WeightGridClass
{
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string SevenDayWeightAverage { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="WeightDataGrid" Margin="440,194,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header=" Date " Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Weight " Binding="{Binding Weight}" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 7-Day average " Binding="{Binding SevenDayWeightAverage}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! I guess problem is that you're not notifying that your gridClassValues changed. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for this purposes. And I'll recommend you to use mvvm pattern in wpf. [Check this step-by-step MVVM giude](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx). It includes INotifyPropertyChanged using and much more.

Comment: MVVM is maybe not the most suitable solution if you have little experience. A simple solution is to add this to your On_click ... method:  WeightDataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you add or delete items to the list (after initialization) this will not notify your UI to get the changes

so you need some mechanism to tell UI that the item in the list has been updated

an easy and good solution is  to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` which will **automatically** notify the UI whenever item added or deleted from the list

```cs
ObservableCollection<WeightGridClass> gridClassValues = new ObservableCollection<WeightGridClass>()
```

read more on [how to respond to changes](https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/)